# Replace column between patterns in one file from another file

Tags: awk

I am trying to write shell script which reads file1, get a specific column from this file. And replace column in file2 with the column extracted from file1 between two patterns .

File1

```
Line1
Line2
.
LineN
ATOM C1 C2 C3
ATOM P23 HI IKJ
ATOM S23 JSK SN
BOND
Many lines
END
```

File2

```
Few Lines
Pattern1
1 C -9.2429 -1.3783 -9.5091 C.3 1 LIG1 0.0555
2 C -10.5865 -0.8658 -8.9679 C.3 1 LIG1 0.0529
3 N -11.3072 -0.5779 -10.1774 N.am 1 LIG1 -0.2940
Patttern2
Lines
```

I want to get the column $2 from file 1 and replace it the the column $2 in file2 between pattern1 and pattern 2.

Output

```
Few Lines
Pattern1
1 C1 -9.2429 -1.3783 -9.5091 C.3 1 LIG1 0.0555
2 P23 -10.5865 -0.8658 -8.9679 C.3 1 LIG1 0.0529
3 S23 -11.3072 -0.5779 -10.1774 N.am 1 LIG1 -0.2940
Patttern2
Lines
```

I have tried few things so far.

```
awk '($1=="ATOM") {print $2}' file1
awk '/pattern1/{flag=1; next} /pattern2/{flag=0} flag' file2
```

I can store the column 2 in file1. Also, lines between both the patterns from file2.

I am sure with something like FNR=NR, I should be able to handle both files at the same time. Any help would be great to proceed further.

Comment: This thread looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53417240/replace-column-between-patterns-in-one-file-from-another-file so please close another one then if both are same.

Answer (score 0):

Per Your question and as You mentioning (FNR==NR) solution You can use this AWK:

```
awk '
( FNR==NR && /^ATOM / ) { atoms[++atomn]=$2; }
( FNR!=NR && /^Patttern2$/ ) { doreplace=0; }
doreplace { $2=atoms[++atomn]; }
( FNR!=NR && /^Pattern1$/ ) { doreplace=1; atomn=0; }
FNR!=NR
' file1 file2
```

I rather prefer this way when dealing with metafile and datafiles:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  if ( ARGC != 3 ) exit(1);
  while ( getline < ARGV[2] ) if ( $0 ~ /^ATOM / ) atoms[++atomn]=$2;
  ARGC=2;
}
/^Patttern2$/ { doreplace=0; }
doreplace { $2=atoms[++atomn]; }
/^Pattern1$/ { doreplace=1; atomn=0; }
1
' file2 file1
```

Both will work on your provided inputs. Here Output:

```
Few Lines
Pattern1
1 C1 -9.2429 -1.3783 -9.5091 C.3 1 LIG1 0.0555
2 P23 -10.5865 -0.8658 -8.9679 C.3 1 LIG1 0.0529
3 S23 -11.3072 -0.5779 -10.1774 N.am 1 LIG1 -0.2940
Patttern2
Lines
```

Both assumes that in metafile (file1) and datafile (file2) you have exactly same number of ATOM and lines between patterns. If You are not able to validate this I would add logic to watch this not to iterate through in-allocated array elements. However in AWK nothing will happen just replacement will be done with empty string instead.